# How to group multiple if condition in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there any better way to do this with fewer lines of code? Sometimes `FirstName` or `SecondName` or `ThirdName` values could be `null` - this code works but I want to improve the quality.

```
if (FirstName != null)
{
    txtEngageeName.Text = FirstName.ToString() ;
}
if (FirstName != null && SecondName != null)
{
    txtEngageeName.Text = FirstName.ToString() + SecondName.ToString();
}
if (FirstName != null && SecondName != null && ThirdName != null)
{
    txtEngageeName.Text = FirstName.ToString() + SecondName.ToString() + ThirdName.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I assume `if (SecondName != null && SecondName != null)` should be `if (FirstName != null && SecondName != null)`

Comment: @SteveFenton Yes it should be if (FirstName != null && SecondName != null)

Comment: "Quality" is a rather subjective term.  Clearly this snippet could get a quick improvement from the Edit + Advanced + Format Document command.  A couple of `else` keywords won't hurt either.  Just removing the null checks is an obvious way ahead, concatenating a null string works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do simple (if you really don't want spaces between entities):

```
txtEngageeName.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", FirstName, SecondName, ThirdName);
```

Nulls will be formatted as empty string.

If you need spaces.

```
txtEngageeName.Text = string.Join(" ", new[] { FirstName, SecondName, ThirdName}.Where(s => s != null));
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!i need the space between the names:)

Comment: @Sajeetharan Added the version with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to get empty `string` when string is `null` and concatenating empty string wont have any effect.

```
txtEngageeName.Text =  (FirstName ?? "") + 
                       (SecondName ?? "") + 
                       (ThirdName ?? "");
```

You can use [ternary ?: Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to add space after first and second name if they are not null.

```
string txtEngageeName = (FirstName == null ? "" : FirstName + " ") + 
                        (SecondName == null ? "" : SecondName + " ") + 
                        (ThirdName  ?? "");
```

Comment: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of bool and 'string'. is there anything to do ?

Comment: There was syntax problem, thanks to @Sergey BereZovskiy who corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the name in the format `Steve Fenton` not `SteveFenton` you can use:

```
var name = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", FirstName, SecondName, ThirdName);

name = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(name, @"\s+", " ");

// Show the result in the text box
txtEngageeName.Text = name;
```

Comment: Thanks! it gives the desired result!

Answer (score 0):

Use `string.Format();`

Like this:

```
txtEngageeName.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
   FirstName,
   SecondName,
   ThirdName
);
```

Comment: You don't need to check nulls within `string.Format` arguments.